# Max Number of Points in Cartesian Path

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to use ROS and Moveit to simulate a tool path which is made up of about 7600 points. I seem to always have issues around point 115, where it will stop calculating poses but still return a success for some reason. Most of the pertinent sections of code are pasted below.

```
    geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose2;
tf2::Quaternion TEMP;


tf2::convert(interm1,interm_pose); // this goal is reachable in a friendly manner.
tf2::Vector3 point, Tpoint;
int i,j;
int numlines;
double datain;
double x,y,z,w,p,r;
std::ifstream infile("Run1_11-22-16.dt");
//std::ifstream infile("Surf11.dt");
std::string line;
std::getline(infile,line);

std::cout<< infile.is_open() << std::endl;
try
{

    numlines = std::stoi(line);
    std::cout << "Your answer : " << numlines << std::endl;
} 
catch (const std::invalid_argument& e)
{
    std::cout << "Invalid answer : " << line << std::endl;
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& e)
{
    std::cout << "Invalid answer : " << line << std::endl;
}
// make for(i = 1;i<=numlines;i++) for full toolpath
for(i = 1;i<=numlines;i++){
    std::getline(infile,line);
    datain = std::stod(line);
    switch(i%7) {
        case 1 : x = datain/1000;
            break;
        case 2 : y = datain/1000;
            break;
        case 3 : z = datain/1000;
            break;
        case 4 : w = datain*pi/180;
            break;
        case 5 : p = datain*pi/180;
            break;
        case 6 : r = datain*pi/180;
            break;
        default : break;
    }
    if((i%7) == 0){
        point[0] = x;
        point[1] = y;
        point[2] = z;
        Tpoint = UFinv*point;

        // here I want to put x,y,z,w,p,r into a std::vector<> object, turn wpr into a quaternion, and push the waypoint for ros.
        //std::cout<<x<< ' '<<y<<' '<<z<<' '<<w<<' '<<p<<' '<<r<<std::endl;

        q1.setRotation(ax2,w);
        q2.setRotation(ax1,p);
        q3.setRotation(ax3,r);
        interm2 = q3*q2*q1; // composition of 3 quaternions representing rotations about x,y, and z respectively.
        TEMP = UFinv.getRotation(); 
        interm1 = interm2*TF; // composing current Toolpath orientation with the UserFrame orientation
        tf2::convert(interm2,interm_pose); // converting tf::Quaternion to geometry_msgs::Quaternion;
        

        target_pose2.position.x = UFtrans[0] + Tpoint[0];
        target_pose2.position.y = UFtrans[1] + Tpoint[1];
        target_pose2.position.z = UFtrans[2] + Tpoint[2];

        target_pose2.orientation.x = interm_pose.x;
        target_pose2.orientation.y = interm_pose.y;
        target_pose2.orientation.z = interm_pose.z;
        target_pose2.orientation.w = interm_pose.w;
        waypoints.push_back(target_pose2);
    }

}


moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
double fraction = move_group.computeCartesianPath(waypoints,
                                         0.02,  // eef_step
                                         1,  // jump_threshold
                                         trajectory);


ROS_INFO("Visualizing plan 4 (cartesian path) (%.2f%% acheived)",fraction * 100.0);
sleep(10);
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there a limit on the maximum number of waypoints one can have?
2. Does anyone have any idea why it suddenly stops calculating trajectories around point 115.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262535/max-number-of-points-in-cartesian-path/) by [jbeck28](https://answers.ros.org/users/28876/jbeck28/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a limit on the maximum number of waypoints one can have?

as far as I know the implementation of `computeCartesianPath(..)` in MoveIt: no, there is no limit. Processing your waypoints will get progressively slower, but that is to be expected.

> Does anyone have any idea why it suddenly stops calculating trajectories around point 115

In my experience `computeCartesianPath(..)` fails when it encounters either: a problem with IK, or if -- at the end -- the computed path violates your jump threshold.

Without more (debug) output it's not necessarily easy to see which of the two it is.

---

If I may make a suggestion: while MoveIt can do these kind of things, I would suggest you take a look at [descartes](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes). It is much better suited for generating tool paths from dense Cartesian trajectories and also supports things like optimisation of trajectories when they are underdefined (ie: 5 dof process with a 6 dof robot).

---

Edit:

> where it will stop calculating poses but still return a success for some reason

quick comment on this btw: `computeCartesianPath(..)` will almost always 'succeed', but the return value (`fraction`) should be used to determine whether it completely processed your list of waypoints. Anything `< 1.0` basically means that it couldn't successfully generate a path through all the poses in the list.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2017-05-26**:
Yes, I second gvdhoorn's comment that Descartes can help, IF you are willing to provide some allowable tolerances on your path poses.

I can not be sure without more info, but imagine your problem is that at some point (e.g., 115) you cross a singularity or joint flip and the Cartesian path request

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2017-05-26**:
fails.  Descartes has the ability to use any provided tolerances to effectively expand the solution space such that you can find continuous paths that avoid such discontinuities and/or singularities.  To summarize, Descartes will find an optimal (in joint distance) path globally, while

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2017-05-26**:
`computeCartesianPath` is acting locally.

After planning, you can take global (IK-valid / discontinuity-free) solution from Descartes and then send it down to `computeCartesianPath`.

**Comment by [jbeck28](https://answers.ros.org/users/28876/jbeck28/) on 2017-06-14**:
Is sending the calculated trajectory from Descartes into ComputeCartesianPath the only way to properly visualize the calculated path? I ask because I've gotten Descartes to calculate some plans for a rather dense tool path I generated, and in RVIZ, it visualizes very slowly.

**Comment by [jbeck28](https://answers.ros.org/users/28876/jbeck28/) on 2017-06-14**:
There are other issues as well, Descartes seems to think it's okay for the tool to flip wildly occasionally despite not using AxialSymmetricPt objects. I think I'll probably start a new thread for that if I can't figure it out soon.

Thanks for all the help so far!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-14**:\

> Descartes seems to think it's okay for the tool to flip wildly occasionally despite not using AxialSymmetricPt objects

this is most likely an IK issue. Descartes relies on IK plugins to provide it with solutions. If the IK acts up, things are going to go wrong.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-14**:
re: visualising a trajectory: I don't know what sort of trajectory you have, but if it's a `JointTrajectory` one, then [moveit_visual_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_visual_tools) has some nice functionality. Should also work with `RobotTrajectory` trajectories.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-14**:
Btw: please do report any issues or unexpected things with Descartes over at [descartes/issues](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/descartes/issues). The developers are very responsive and I believe would welcome any feedback you might have.